# Limpar valor de um id com jquery

Tags: jquery

Colegas.

Tenho um select do qual está trazendo os estoques de um banco de dados. Estou capturando dessa forma:

```
<select name='estoque' id='estoqueProdutos'>
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option>
 <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
function alterar(){
    var estoques = $('#estoqueProdutos').val();
    var estoque = document.getElementById("estoque").value = estoques;
}
```

Cada estoque irá limitar a quantidade do botão abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que está representado da seguinte forma:

```
$('.value-plus1').on('click', function(){
    var estoqueProduto = document.getElementById("estoque").value;

    var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value1'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)+1;                                      
    if(newVal <= estoqueProduto){
       document.getElementById("quantidade").value = newVal;
       divUpd.text(newVal);
    }   
});
$('.value-minus1').on('click', function(){
    var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value1'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)-1;                                      
    if(newVal>=1){ 
        divUpd.text(newVal); 
        document.getElementById("quantidade").value = newVal;
    }
});
```

Até aqui tudo certo, o problema é que ao selecionar o valor 3 e depois o valor 2, o valor 3 continua aparecendo. Gostaria de que ao mudar o valor do estoque, o número da quantidade voltasse para o número 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma: sempre que o select de produtos for alterado vc altera o valor da quantidade para 1.
Exemplo:

```js
$('#estoqueProdutos').on('change', function()
{
    $('#quantidade').val('1')
});
```

```html
<select name='estoque' id='estoqueProdutos'>
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option>
 <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="quantidade" value="3">
```

Comment: Obrigado Jessika.